# `string_agg` in postgresql maximum length

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

For example, the function `string_agg(name,',')` returns `abc,d,e,f,g`.
Is there any way to set maximum length for the function `string_agg` to return only first `N` characters `abc,d,e,...` or `ab...`?
P.S. No matter how it will be splitted.

Comment: Have you tried to limit the number of rows with `LIMIT 10` for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just take the first "n" characters after doing the aggregation:

```
select left(string_agg(name, ','), N) as FirstN
```